# How to count all records if use alias in select query?

Tags: yii2, sphinx

I use Sphinx with Yii2 and need to query with filter by jSON field.

```
$query = new \yii\sphinx\Query();
$query->from('announcements');
$query->addSelect("*");
$query->addSelect(new Expression("IN(filters['color'], 'blue', 'red', 'green') AS f_color"));
$query->where("is_active = 1");
$query->andWhere("f_color = 1");
$announces = $query->all();
```

There is jSON field `filters` in my Sphinx index. For example:

```
[filters] => {"brand":"Toyota","model":"Prius","color":"red","price":"12000"... etc]
```

It works OK. But now I need to make a pagination... and there is a problem when I try to count records before `$query->all()`

```
$count = $query->count(); // Return error "no such filter attribute 'f_color'"
```

Generated query was:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM announcements WHERE ( is_active = 1 ) AND ( f_color = 1 )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`count()` by default replaces the `select` part with `*` and this is where your alias is defined hence the error.

There are different ways to achieve it like:

- use ActiveDataProvider like described [here](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-sphinx/blob/master/docs/guide/usage-data-providers.md),
- use META information like described [here](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-sphinx/blob/master/docs/guide/usage-meta.md)

Since you want to make a pagination I would go with the first example.

Comment: Thank you!! Solution is:

showMeta(true)->search()['meta']['total_found']